# Difference between service and container in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I was going through `volumes_from` option in docker compose. Apparently you can import a volumes from either a container or a service. From the docker compose documentation it is:

> **volumes_from**
>
> Mount all of the volumes from another service or container, optionally
>   specifying read-only access(ro) or read-write(rw).
>
> ```
> volumes_from:
>  - service_name
>  - service_name:ro
>  - container:container_name
>  - container:container_name:rw
> ```
>
> Note: The container:... formats are only supported in the version 2
>   file format. In version 1, you can use container names without marking
>   them as such:
>
> ```
> - service_name
> - service_name:ro
> - container_name
> - container_name:rw
> ```

I am confused here what is the difference between containers and services here?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Services and container are related but both are different things.

A service can be run by one or multiple containers.
With `docker` you can handle containers and with `docker-compose` you can handle services.

For example:

Let's say that we have this `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
web:
  image: example/my_web_app:latest
  expose:
    - 80
  links:
    - db 

db:
  image: postgres:latest
```

This compose file defines two services, `web` and `db`.

When you run `docker-compose up`, Assuming that the project directory is `test1` then compose will start 2 containers named `test1_db_1` and `test1_web_1`.

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE        COMMAND          ...      NAMES
1c1683e871dc   test1_web    "nginx -g"       ...      test1_web_1
a41360558f96   test1_db     "postgres -d"    ...      test1_db_1
```

So, in this point you have 2 services and 1 container for each.

But you could scale the service named `web` to use 5 containers.

```
$ docker-compose scale web=5
Creating and starting 2 ... done
Creating and starting 3 ... done
Creating and starting 4 ... done
Creating and starting 5 ... done
```

In this point you have 2 services and 6 containers

```
$ docker ps -a  
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE        COMMAND         ...      NAMES
1bf4c939263f   test1_web    "nginx -g"      ...      test1_web_3
d3033964a44b   test1_web    "nginx -g"      ...      test1_web_4
649bbda4d0b0   test1_web    "nginx -g"      ...      test1_web_5
a265ea406727   test1_web    "nginx -g"      ...      test1_web_2
1c1683e871dc   test1_web    "nginx -g"      ...      test1_web_1
a41360558f96   test1_db     "postgres -d'   ...      test1_db_1
```

Additionally, with docker-compose you can run subcommand against one or more services.

```
$docker-compose stop web
```

Comment: This answer was so good that I actually broke your perfect "69" upvotes by giving it a thumbs up too

Answer (score 1):

i cant fully answer your question as i dont understand about services myself.
However, I do understand volumes_from in relation to containers and so this will answer half your question :)
A partial answer is better than none?

CONTAINER A

```
volumes: /my/shared/directory
container_name:ca
```

CONTAINER B

```
volumes_from:ca
```

Now container B will have a new directory in it /my/shared/directory which is mounted from container A - the contents of the directory in container B will be exactly the same as the contents of the directory in container A

if you discover about services plz let me know